# How to do >git diff --no-index file1 file2 in Gitkraken

Tags: git-diff, gitkraken

Using the git CLI I can compare two files. If those files are untracked I can do so by using the `--no-index` argument:

```
git diff --no-index file1 file2
```

I couldn't find a way to do so in the gitkraken (gui) client.

The usual ways of doing a diff, like for branches, commits or by viewing the `History` of a file don't apply because the files are untracked.